# How to check if an element exists in linked list

Tags: go

I am trying to find if an element exists in my linked list so that duplicate elements are not added.

My code follows [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Bw2ZeP4sIOm):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func (e Ensemble) EstVide() bool {
    return e.ensemble == nil
}
func (e Ensemble) Card() int {
    return e.longueur
}

type Cellule struct {
    elem    int
    suivant *Cellule
}

type Ensemble struct {
    ensemble *Cellule
    longueur int
}

func (c Cellule) String() string {
    if c.suivant == nil {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v}", c.elem)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", c.elem)
}

func (e Ensemble) String() string {
    if e.EstVide() {
        return ""
    }
    res := "{"
    for curr := e.ensemble; curr != nil; curr = curr.suivant {
        res += fmt.Sprintf("%s ", curr)
    }
    return res[:len(res)-1]
}

func (e Ensemble) Appartient(valeur int) bool {
    body := e.String()
    for i := 0; i < e.Card(); i++ {
        if valeur == int(body[i]) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func (e *Ensemble) Ajouter(valeur int) {
    if !e.Appartient(valeur) {
        e.ensemble = &Cellule{elem: valeur, suivant: e.ensemble}
        e.longueur++
    }
}

func main() {
    monEns := Ensemble{}
    fmt.Printf("Nb d'éléments dans monEns %v\n", monEns.Card())
    fmt.Printf("monEns = %v\n", monEns)

    monEns.Ajouter(42)
    monEns.Ajouter(10)
    monEns.Ajouter(20)
    monEns.Ajouter(10)

    fmt.Printf("Nb d'éléments dans monEns %v\n", monEns.Card())
    fmt.Printf("monEns = %v \n", monEns)
}
```

The output (`{10 20 10 42}` includes a duplicate element (`10`). How can I prevent this?

Comment: You walk the linked list and check for the given value. If you don’t know how to walk a linked list, there are probably a million solutions for that in various languages on the web.

Comment: Can you please try to provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - ideally something that can be run in the [playground](https://go.dev/play/). The code you have provided relies on methods like `Card` and `EstVide` which you have not provided. You already have code to walk the list but appear to be converting it into a string for the comparison?

Comment: The main reason is because you do weird things with concatenating numbers to strings and then comparing their byte values against number again. Remove all that stuff from your `Appartient` function and just loop through your list, comparing `Cellule.elem` against the new value. The String() methods and the current comparison in `Appartient` don't make sense.

Comment: Please take a look in the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Bw2ZeP4sIOm) I linked in my edit. You will note a commented line; uncomment this and it will demonstrate that your comparison always fails. There is no reason to change the structure into text in order to carry out the comparison (its inefficient; it could be made to work but not the way you are doing it). Something like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/Yp8eM640en3) is simpler.